# Simple question: How to show values on top of barplot in R?

Tags: r, label, bar-chart

Im new to R and I am trying to have my values shown on top of my barplot. They do appear, however they are displaced. Anyone know how to correct for this?

```
values <- c(11978, 151417.5, 593, 2148)
group <- c("Reef", "Stone Reef", "Biogenic reef", "Potential Biogenic Reef") 
barplot(values, ylim=c(0,170000),                                      
        names.arg = group)
text(values, labels=values, pos=3)
title("Barplot")
```

Hope you can help :)

Comment: note saving the return value of `barplot`: `bp <- barplot(values); text(bp, values, values, pos = 3, xpd = NA)`

Comment: Thank for the help! Do you know how to change the font size of the labels on the x-axis?

Comment: it's `barplot(values, names.arg = group, cex.names = 1.25)` which would be the same as setting this option in `par`: `par(cex.axis = 1.25); barplot(values, names.arg = group)` but this one would apply to both axes until you reset the pars or set it back manually `par(cex.axis = 1)`

Comment: for finer control, i usually end up using `text` which has more options than `axis` which is what draws the labels, for example you can rotate text `bp <- barplot(values); text(bp, diff(par('usr')[3:4]) * -0.05, group, srt = 45, adj = 1, xpd = NA)`

Answer (score -1):

@rawr's solution, or consider <del>growing a hipster beard</del> plotting with ggplot2, and on log10 scale!  Check this out:

```r
tibble(
    values = values,
    group = group
) %>% 
    ggplot(aes(x = group, y = values)) + 
    geom_col() +
    geom_text(aes(label = values), nudge_y = 0.3) +
    theme_bw() + 
    theme(panel.grid.major.x = element_blank()) +
    scale_y_log10()
```

[image]